# I had myself sit in the driver's seat. : Is this possible?

Tags: grammar

I said (1)'I had myself sit in the driver's seat' by mistake in the sense that (2)he let me sit in the driver's seat. How about (3)'He gave me a ride in the driver's seat' ?

Are these (1) (2) (3) too too strange? Or, can we use any one if I want to?

Answer (score 1):

Saying "I had him do something" means "I organised things so that he did something". For example "I had my wife make coffee for me this morning" suggests that I asked her and she agreed to make coffee.

Saying "I had myself sit in the driver's seat" suggest that you arranged matters so that you would drive. You might say "I had myself sit in the driver's seat and I asked my wife to sit in the back to stop the kids from arguing." It is rather odd since most days you don't organise seating in the car.

"He let me sit in the driver's seat" is fine. Without further context, it suggests that you *don't* drive, only sit "He showed me the new F1 racing car and he let me sit in the driving seat!"

"He gave me a ride in the driver's seat" is odd.  If you are driving, then you are giving him a ride. Riding in a car implies that you are not driving the car. Riding in the driving seat seems to mean you are in the driving seat, the car is moving, but you aren't driving. That makes it odd.

I'd probably just split the sentence up.  "We went for a ride, and he let me drive".

Comment: I need some more comment on (3). Would like to know its possibility further. How odd is this?  Can I use (3) depending on the situation, in the sense of "He let me sit in the driver's seat" ?

Comment: .....And, finally, can we use (3), or not ? Please clarify.

Comment: No.  If you want to say "He let me sit in the driver's seat" don't say "He gave me a ride in the driver's seat.". The expression in (3) is odd and doesn't mean the same as "He let me sit in the driver's seat".

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they are strange and somewhat incorrect.

```
I took a ride at the backseat
```

Would be what I'd use in this case.

```
He gave me a ride, I sat at the back.
```